# How to make remote calls to Instagram using PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, instagram

I have the following code being executed on WordPress hosted on Middlehost hosting. Code works fine locally but when testing online it returns the message "Please try again in a few minutes".

I wanted to confirm if I have integrated the code incorrectly or is this some sort of limitation with Middlehost or WordPress itself.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

function getVideoLink($reel_link)
{
   
    $reel_link = $reel_link . "/?hl=en";
   
    $reel_id = preg_match('/reels?\/(.*?)\//', $reel_link, $matches) ? $matches[1] : null;
    if (!$reel_id) {
        return array("", "");
    }

    $link = "https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/";
    $headers = array(
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36'
    );
    $variables = '{"child_comment_count":3,"fetch_comment_count":40,"has_threaded_comments":true,"parent_comment_count":24,"shortcode":"' . $reel_id . '"}';
    $params = array(
        'hl' => 'en',
        'query_hash' => 'b3055c01b4b222b8a47dc12b090e4e64',
        'variables' => $variables
    );
    $url = $link . '?' . http_build_query($params);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    try {
        $resp = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = json_decode($resp, true);
        $video_link = $data['data']['shortcode_media']['video_url'];
        $image_preview = $data['data']['shortcode_media']['display_url'];

        return array($video_link, $image_preview);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return array("", "");
    } finally {
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
?>
```

I was trying to access Instagram GraphQL by sending a request packaged with header and payload (with the reel id to be downloaded). I'm expecting the request to return the download links.

Comment: What HTTP response code are you getting? I wonder if you are getting a back-off response, maybe due to your web host IP address being blacklisted.